# Writing variables to ".txt" file in R

Tags: r, matlab, file-io

I am writing variables to a ".txt" file in **R**. I write the following code:

```
textfile=file.path("tuning_parameter.txt");
printer = file(textfile,"a+");
write(c(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6),textfile,sep = " ",append = TRUE);
write("\n", textfile, append=TRUE)
close(printer)
```

I run the code twice and got

```
1 0.02301807 0.5829662 1.391419 0.0452473
0.07409543
1 0.02301807 0.5829662 1.391419 0.0452473
0.07409543
```

My question is why the 6-th variable changed to the next line since I didn't use any "\n". Another question, is there any way in **R** to control the digits of the written variables such as

```
fprintf(fid, '%s %10.4f %10.4f \n',V1,V2,V3);
```

in **MatLab**?

Comment: Why not just `write.table`?

Comment: @alistaire I need text file.

Comment: That's what `write.table` makes: whitespace-delimited text files, which you can save as .txt if you like.

Answer (score 2):

`write` function has `ncolumns` parameter that is defaulted to 5 for non-character vectors:

```
write(x, file = "data",
      ncolumns = if(is.character(x)) 1 else 5,
      append = FALSE, sep = " ")
```

try:

```
V1 <- 1
V2 <- 0.02301807 
V3 <- 0.5829662 
V4 <- 1.391419 
V5 <- 0.0452473
V6 <- 0.07409543
textfile=file.path("tuning_parameter.txt");
printer = file(textfile,"a+");
write(c(V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6), textfile,sep = " ",append = TRUE, ncolumns = 6);
write("\n", textfile, append=TRUE)
close(printer)
```

, which produces single line.

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly the answer.